# why does the page not display any information

Tags: google-app-engine

i am learning how ton use Jinja2 template   for google app engine.This is the sample code which i have writen but it doesnot display anything when i run them.

```
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'], autoescape=True)





class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class login(db.Model):
    user_fname=db.StringProperty(required=True)
    user_lname=db.StringProperty(required=True)
    user_name=db.StringProperty(required=True)
    user_email=db.EmailProperty(required=True)
    user_password=db.StringProperty(required=True)
    repeat_password=db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created=db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class MainPage(Handler):

    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")
    def render_page(self,user_fname="",user_lname="",user_name="",user_email="",user_password="",repeat_password="",error="" ):
        prof=db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM login")
        self.render("index.html",user_fname=user_fname,
        user_lname=user_lname,
        user_name=user_name,
        user_email=user_email,
        user_password=user_password,
        repeat_password=repeat_password,
        error=error)




    def post(self):
        user_fname=self.request.get("user_fname")
        user_name=self.request.get("user_name")

        user_lname=self.request.get("user_lname")
        user_email=self.request.get("user_email")
        repeat_password=self.request.get("repeat_password")
        user_password=self.request.get("user_password")

        if (user_name and user_email and user_fname and user_lname and user_password and repeat_password):
          if not(user_password==repeat_password):
            error="passwords does not match check again carefull"
            self.render_page(user_fname,user_lname,user_name,user_email,"","",error)
          else:
            #store in the database to be used later
            a=login(
                user_fname=user_fname,
                 user_lname=user_lname,
                 user_name=user_name,
                user_email=user_email,
                user_password=user_password,
                repeat_password=repeat_password)
            a.put()

            self.redirect("/profile")
        else:
          error="please fill out the details above"
          self.render_page(user_fname,user_lname,user_name,user_email,"","",error)

class Thankshandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("profile.html")
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ ('/', MainPage),('/profile',Thankshandler)],debug=True)
```

and  in the profile.html i have added

```
{% for next in prof %}           
     <ul>
       <h1>{{next.user_name}}</hi>
     </ul> 

    {% endfor %}
```

but it display nothing. I wonder what is the problem if any body can help please.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What a mess.  I am not going to go through all the code, but the cause of your problem is that you are not passing "prof" with its properties to the template profile.html.  Study jinja, and how to pass data to the template.